# Crash after open my flutter app on Samsung galaxy A10

Tags: android, flutter

Hello after upgrade I have user who have crash, I don't understand why.

here is the logs

Problem 1:

```
  Fatal Exception: i.b.a.b.i.b: Complete with: result l.b.m1.a$b@74d2219
               at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzh(zzw.java:5)
               at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zza(zzw.java:8)
               at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run(zzz.java:27)
               at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
               at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
               at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run(-.java:4)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Problem 2:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.0).
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:19)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y.run(-.java:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8625)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Can you confirm whicj version com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore  are you using at  build.gradle file ?

Comment: I have com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0

Comment: can you update it to latest one which is : 30.3.1

Answer (score 0):

you have to add **internet permissions**, copy this code in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Than you I will try

Comment: If it cause on permission, why it appear only with this spécific user mobile and not for all users ?

Comment: did you mean on specific device?

Comment: only on one device samsung galaxy A10, only one crash / 1000 users

Comment: I launch an upgrade with permission , but have always this error, now on galaxy S8